# jQuery .Click on <a> not getting triggered on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

I have a dropdown menu for changing the language. In order to do that I need to react to the OnClick event and trigger my own code, so I have the following jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".user-info-menu .dropdown-menu a").click(function(e) {
           var $this = jQuery( this ),
           lang_code = $this.data( 'lang' ); // for this you need to add an attribute data-lang="nl" for each A href link

           // Display a notification or loading indicator
           show_loading_bar(90); 

           $.post ('/i18n/setlang/', {
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
             lang: lang_code,
             language: lang_code
           }).done(function(response){
             show_loading_bar(100);
             window.location.reload();
           });
    });
});
```

Now ... this seems to be working perfectly on desktop browsers, but as soon as I try it on my iPhone / iPad or android tablet, it doesn't seem to be working at all. For some reason the .click doesn't get triggered.

I've already tried many things I found on the web (touchstart, vclick, tap, ... ) but sadly haven't been able to get it working.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Add a `return false;` inside your `.click()` .

Comment: put an alert on the first line of function to see if it really gets there.

Comment: @user3281404 it actually doesn't even get in there on a mobile device at all.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it looks like the .click event doesn't get triggered at all when opening the page on a mobile device. On a desktop device it works, desktop device with user agents set to iPad works as well. Physical iPad / iPhone or iPad / iPhone simulator nor android tablet seems to work.

Comment: no idea then. i would check this by remove all the code inside the function and put an alert. if it doesn't works then i would give <a id="linkTest"> an id and check it $("#linkTest").click(function(e)

Comment: @user3281404 to me it seems like the .click is getting triggered on desktops, but not on mobile devices. Sounds a bit logic to me since on mobile devices there is no mouse ... hence clicking is tough. Question is ... what should I be using ...

Comment: @user3281404 Tried it ... same thing. Works on desktop not on mobile devices.